# HDFS file path issue in Hadoop 2

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I am getting fileNotFoundException in the mentioned line below. Earlier in Hadoop 1 this was functional. But now it throws a FileNotFoundException

```
        Path localManifestFolder;
        Path localManifestPath = new Path("hdfs:///WordCount/write/manifest");
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        FileSystem fs = null;
        try {
            URI localHDFSManifestUri = new URI("
                hdfs:///WordCount/write");
            fs = FileSystem.get(localHDFSManifestUri, conf);
            localManifestFolder = new Path("hdfs:///WordCount/write");
            FileStatus[] listOfFiles = fs.listStatus(localManifestFolder); // Getting Error in this line
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
          throw ex;
        }
```

Exception :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs:/WordCount/write does not exist.
```

Please tell me why such thing is happening

Comment: try using rpc address to the hdfs file. Your default-rpc address is your FQDN(Fully qualified domain name):8020. Then it may work.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have your core-site.xml on the classpath, then you need to specify the HDFS location (otherwise defaults to local filesystem)

For example

```
hdfs://namenode.fqdn:8020/WordCount
```